# SPSS: Import "Stacked" Text-Datafile

Tags: import, statistics, text-files, spss

I have an ascii data file with the following layout:

```
year    var1    var2    var3
1995    asdf    asdf    asdf
1996    asdf    asdf    asdf
1997    asdf    asdf    asdf
1998    asdf    asdf    asdf
1999    asdf    asdf    asdf


year    var4    var5
1995    asdf    asdf
1996    asdf    asdf
1997    asdf    asdf
1998    asdf    asdf
1999    asdf    asdf
```

Obviously the values are different, and numeric, but this should illustrate the point.

Basically, my variables are 'stacked' in blocks of 24 lines (1972-1995) each. What is the easiest way to import them into SPSS? I do have variable names as headers over every block and year-info for every line. Maybe if someone could tell me how this specific format is called (and even why one would ever use it!), I can properly google it...

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes this is annoying. The [US census does it sometimes](https://www.census.gov/popest/data/counties/totals/pre-1980/tables/e7079co.txt). I have no quick answer, there are some different examples of using `DATA LIST` within an `INPUT PROGRAM` that might work, as well as the `REPEATING` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to put these in separate files, read them individually, and then join them with MATCH FILES using the year as the id variable.  You would treat the second file as a table.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something I only have to do once, I would probably do it in Excel then import that data file into SPSS.